# Can I use one subdomain to serve multiple websites on different port with nginx?

Tags: nginx

Is there any way that I can use one subdomain/domain, i.e `mysub.domain.com` or `domain.com` to serve multiple websites on different port?

I am using nginx and below is my config for local development.

```
server {

        listen      1900;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   D:\testwebsite;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            expires -1;

            add_header Pragma "no-cache";

            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";

            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   D:\prodwebsite;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            expires -1;

            add_header Pragma "no-cache";

            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";

            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }
```

As per the config, I am currently serving two differents website, prod(port 80) and test(port 1900). Can this be done with using domain or subdomain?

I've never done this with a subdomain/domain before so I am not entirely sure how it works. I've been doing some research but just could not fully grasped it.

Comment: You certainly can - exactly as you already did it. Just add more `server` blocks, each one on different port. You can have both different ports on the same domain/subdomain and different domains/subdomains on the same port.

Comment: So, are you saying that if have a subdomain, for example, `test.domain.com`, i can serve two websites like so, one for `test.domain.com` and another one for `test.domain.com:1900` ?

Comment: If not using SSL, both servers can (and should) listen on port 80, no need to use other. Two different websites means two different source folders, so if, for example, test uses `root D:\testwebsite;`, prod should use other folder, for example `root D:\prodwebsite;`.  Also, `server_name` directive should be different for each server: `server_name domain.com;` and `server_name mysub.domain.com;`.

Comment: Yes - as long as you access your websites through the proper port (provided in the URL) it will work. If you do not provide a port in the URL - the browser will use port 80 for `http` and 443 for `https` URLs.